# iPhone App Update. "createSymbolicLinkAtPath" released?

Tags: ios

I am using the symbolic link with iPhoneApp.

```
NSString* js_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"js" ofType:nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if (js_path != nil) {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString* move_js_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/js",  [paths objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSError *error; 
    if ([fm createSymbolicLinkAtPath:move_js_path withDestinationPath:js_path error:&error]) {
    } else {}
}
```

I updated the application program. It becomes impossible to read the file afterwards.

However, the file was able to be read by reinstalling it after the application program had been deleted once.

Is there a problem in this code?

Answer (score 0):

If anyones wondering about this, the reason is the application moves directory every time it's updated, the solution might be to use relative paths bundles are located at /var/mobile/Applications/[unique id that changes every update]/app.app whereas the documents directory is located at /var/mobile/Applications/[unique id that changes every update]/Documents so a symlink from Documents to the bundle will always work if it uses something like ../[bundlepath lastPathComponent]/Documents

ofc it's a good idea to build the relativeness from the directories you get at runtime rather than hard coding it, incase these relative paths change in the future.